# How to write to a csv file a txt file line by line

Tags: python

I am trying to write to an csv file from a txt file, but instead of putting the whole line in a cell it puts each letter separately.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
# opening the csv file in 'w+' mode
file = open('My_CSV.csv', 'w+', newline ='')
# writing the data into the file
with file: 
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(Lines)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: have you read the documention for the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)? What is a row supposed to be? What is a row in your code?